# What account is used by sp_send_dbmail?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

We ran into an issue yesterday with a stored procedure that calls sp_send_dbmail. The stored procedure is called from a scheduled job, and the job is explicitly set with a domain account that has full control on a folder, on the same server.

The issue was with attachment, where when trying to send an email with an attachment I was getting an error message: "sp_send_dbmail file attachment invalid"

So when I added the Engine service account, which is different from the SQL Agent, it worked fine. Looking at the error and how it was fixed, the answer is clear, sp_send_dbmail is using the Engine account and not the Agent account.

The thing is, that the other DBA claims the Engine account was never granted access to the folder, only the Agent account. So I was wondering if  this could be due to some change in the permissions for the Agent account.

That's very weird.

I was hoping if you guys could point me at some documentation, as I couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: I've voted to migrate this to the [dba.se] site; I think it would help if you also clarified that you're talking about attachments and access to them in your title.

Comment: Sure, I should've posted it there.

Comment: I *think*, but can't verify or find documentation; that the account sql server is running as will need to permissions to the folder. I remember this being an issue when I changed a server and didn't set it up with a domain account but someone had it accessing attachments on a network share. :|

Comment: Generally speaking, when accessing files from SQL Server, it's the Data Engine's service account that needs access. That's regardless of the context of the query. So, if that query is being run in agent but accessing a file to attach to an email, then the Data Engine Service Account needs access. If I am using SSMS and use `OPENROWSET` to read an Excel file on my local machine, then the Data Engine's Service Account needs to be able to access my local machine's storage (not something I recommend). There are a couple of exceptions however; running a package through SSISDB is one such example.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. As I mentioned, that's the way that I see it too. But it's weird the job was working without the Engine service account, and only with the Agent account. I'm still trying to find some documentation about it.